# Installation problem for z-ram config

Tags: 20.04, zram

I installed zram following this [tutorial](https://installati.one/install-zram-config-ubuntu-20-04/) with apt-get, my system is kubuntu 20.04. It seems to have worked, but the problem is that zram usage and swap are merged now, for instance `free -m` gives

```
               total        used       free      shared     buff/cache  available
Mem.:          7747         584        5680         148        1482        6716
Swap:          5921           0        5921
```

Before installing z-ram I had 2 GB of swap. So the question is how can I split this, I want information about z-ram and disk swap separately.